# SQL Server stored procedure - reference two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am trying to create a select stored procedure where it takes a value from one table and sets this as a parameter for the second table.

As below I would like the user to input a reference number, which then gathers the registration ID from table 1, then performs a search in table two based on the registration ID, reference number and registration ID are both unique.

Reference number only exists in tableOne, registration_id exists in both

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPSelect1
    @Reference_Number NVARCHAR(10),
    @Registration_ID NVARCHAR(10)
AS
    SET @Registration_ID = (tblOne.registration_id WHERE reference_number = @Reference_Number)

    SELECT * 
    FROM tblTwo 
    WHERE tblTwo.registration_id = @Registration_ID
END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is this:

```
SET @Registration_ID = (SELECT tblOne.registration_id where reference_number = @Reference_Number)
```

Or you could combine the two statements using a JOIN:

```
SELECT tblTwo.*
FROM   tblTwo
JOIN   tblOne ON tblTwo.registration_id = tblOne.registration_id
WHERE  tblOne.reference_number = @Reference_Number
```

Comment: I have used the join one and got it working, thankyou very much

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
select * 
from tblTwo 
where tblTwo.registration_id IN (SELECT tblOne.registration_id
                                 FROM tblOne
                                 WHERE reference_number = @Reference_Number)
```

Answer (score 0):

> i would like the user to input a reference number

Then your stored proc should only require a reference number as an input parameter. It can then query `tblOne` to find the registration ID corresponding to that reference number, and then query `tblTwo` using the registration ID in it's `WHERE` clause.

> reference number and registration ID are both unique

Since you specified that the two fields are unique, I would use an `INNER JOIN`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SPSelect1
    @Reference_Number NVARCHAR(10)

AS

BEGIN 
    SELECT *
    FROM tblTwo
    INNER JOIN tblOne
    ON tblTwo.Registration_ID = tblOne.Registration_ID
    WHERE tblOne.Reference_Number = @Reference_Number                                        
END

GO
```